# What does "top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;" mean?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am reading a guide from this [site](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) about a technique on centering elements.

I read the CSS code,

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

And I read the explanation too.

But what I don't understand is the part that explains "top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;".

It says,

> Setting top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; gives the browser a new bounding box for the block. At this point the block will fill all available space in its offset parent, which is the body or position: relative; container. Developer.mozilla.org: For absolutely positioned elements, the top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edge of the element’s containing block (what the element is positioned relative to).

What does this mean? Bounding box? Fill all the available space?

How does "top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;" work? does it take the 4 sides of a box and stretch them to fill the container? Is that how the values work?

What actually happens when I set "top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;"?

I'm completely lost at this explanation and I would like somebody to rephrase, restate and explain it to me in a more simple and understandable fashion.

Thank you.

Comment: The quote directly answers your question. "the block will fill all available space in the parent, which is the body or `position: relative;` container". and "the top, right, bottom, and left properties specify the offset from the container".

Answer (score 45):

What happens when you use `left` and `right` (or `top` and `bottom`) at the *same* time is confusing because the spec [[6.3. Absolute positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abs-pos)] tells us that:

> For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on
> a block-level element, this property is an *offset* from the padding
> edge of that element.

So how can setting **position** affect the *size* of an element?  The reason stems from how widths are calculated, which is buried in another section of the spec, [[8.1. The width of absolute or fixed positioned, non-replaced elements]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#size-and-position-details).

If you specify both `left` and `right` and your element's `width` is *not* `auto`, then what you are saying really doesn't make sense, and `right` is ignored (all statements apply equally well to top/bottom/height):

> If none of left/right/width is auto...the values are over-constrained, ignore
> the value for left (in case the direction property of the containing
> block is rtl) or right (in case direction is ltr) and solve for that
> value.

But if your element *has no width set, or width is (the default) `auto`*,  this rule kicks in:

> If width is auto, left and right are not auto, then solve for width.

Finally, the equation given that determines the values for these elements is:

> 'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' +
> 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' +
> 'right' = width of containing block

We can clearly see that after plugging in our values for `left` and `right` and the others, `width` is the unsolved (and unconstrained) variable,  which will turn out to be `width of containing box - left - right` (more or less) or to put it another way: "fill in the space between the offsets".

Answer (score 33):

You can make 100% width and 100% height using top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

Example: You have one div there is no fixed width & height for that div. in this case you can apply this style and make 100% width & height.

```
div{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/77fdcvux/)**

Comment: To simulate the exact same output here as with `top, bottom, right, left ` combination, add the following CSS Rule `body{margin:0; padding:0;}` and you will have the same look with both approaches

Comment: Why can't we just use `width: 100%`?

Comment: You can use 100% also but you can't give theight 100%. for height you have use 'top' and 'bottom' position and width:100%

Answer (score 8):

Positioning a div or an element **absolute** like below css snippet expands the element to take parent's full width and height. If parent is a full page element the styled element will take full page. If there is more content available below or above they will be visible as they should.

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
```

Positioning as **fixed** on the other hand makes it full screen. Additionally it won't scroll away rather consider it as something on top of your page(generally) which is independent from the other elements of page which can be scrolled as usual(wont be visible if fixed element has opacity : 1 and is full page).

```
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `inset: 0*`, which is equivalent to `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0`.
Supported in all major browsers.

```
 position: absolute;
 inset: 0;
```